RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (51) must match the size of tensor b (50) at non-singleton dimension 1
import torch
import torch.nn as nn 
import math 
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, TensorDataset 
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast

class PositionalEncoding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, seq_length, d_model):
        super(PositionalEncoding, self).__init__()
        self.seq_length = seq_length 
        self.d_model = d_model 
        self.pos_encoding = self._generate_positional_encoding(seq_length, d_model)

    def _generate_positional_encoding(self, seq_length, d_model):
        pos_encoding = torch.zeros(seq_length, d_model, dtype=torch.float32)

        for pos in range(seq_length):
            for i in range(0, d_model, 2):
                angle = pos / 10000 ** (2 * i / d_model)
                pos_encoding[pos, i] = torch.sin(torch.tensor(angle, dtype=torch.float32))
                if i + 1 < d_model:
                    pos_encoding[pos, i + 1] = torch.cos(torch.tensor(angle, dtype=torch.float32))
        return pos_encoding 

    def forward(self, x):
        # Dynamically adjust positional encoding based on the input tensor size
        pos_encoding = self.pos_encoding[:x.size(1), :]
        return x + pos_encoding

class MultiHeadAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads):
        super(MultiHeadAttention, self).__init__()
        self.d_model = d_model 
        self.num_heads = num_heads 
        self.head_dim = d_model // num_heads

        self.W_q = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
        self.W_k = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
        self.W_v = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)

        self.W_out = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
    
    def split_heads(self, x):
        batch_size, seq_length, _ = x.size()
        x = x.view(batch_size, seq_length, self.num_heads, self.head_dim)
        return x.permute(0, 2, 1, 3) 

    def combined_heads(self, x):
        batch_size, num_heads, seq_length, _ = x.size()
        x = x.permute(0, 2, 1, 3).contiguous()
        return x.view(batch_size, seq_length, self.d_model)
    
    def forward(self, Q, K, V, mask=None):
        Q_transformed = self.W_q(Q) 
        K_transformed = self.W_k(K) 
        V_transformed = self.W_v(V) 

        Q_split = self.split_heads(Q_transformed) 
        K_split = self.split_heads(K_transformed) 
        V_split = self.split_heads(V_transformed) 

        attention_scores = torch.matmul(Q_split, K_split.transpose(-2, -1)) / math.sqrt(self.head_dim)
        if mask is not None:
            attention_scores = attention_scores.masked_fill(mask == 0, -1e9)

        attention_weigths = nn.functional.softmax(attention_scores, dim=-1)
        attention_outputs = torch.matmul(attention_weigths, V_split)
        
        output = self.combined_heads(attention_outputs)
        output = self.W_out(output)
        return output 

# Masking function 
def generate_squre_subsequent_mask(sz):
    mask = (torch.triu(torch.ones(sz, sz)) == 1).transpose(0, 1)
    mask = mask.float().masked_fill(mask == 0, float('-inf')).masked_fill(mask == 1, float(0.0))
    return mask

class PositionWiseFeedForward(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, d_ff):
        super(PositionWiseFeedForward, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(d_model, d_ff) 
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(d_ff, d_model) 
        self.gelu = nn.GELU() 
    
    def forward(self, x): 
        x = self.fc1(x) 
        x = self.gelu(x) 
        x = self.fc2(x) 
        return x 

class TransformerDecoderBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads, d_ff, dropout=0.1):
        super(TransformerDecoderBlock, self).__init__()
        self.attention = MultiHeadAttention(d_model, num_heads) 
        self.feedforwardNN = PositionWiseFeedForward(d_model, d_ff) 
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout) 
        self.norm1 = nn.LayerNorm(d_model) 
        self.norm2 = nn.LayerNorm(d_model) 

    def forward(self, input_tensor, mask):
        attention_output = self.attention(input_tensor, input_tensor, input_tensor, mask) 
        input_tensor_out = input_tensor + self.dropout(attention_output)
        input_tensor_norm = self.norm1(input_tensor_out) 
        output_ = self.feedforwardNN(input_tensor_norm) 
        output_ = self.dropout(output_)
        output_ = self.norm2(output_) 
        
        return output_
        
class Transformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, d_ff, num_heads, vocab, seq_length, num_layers, dropout=0.1):
        super(Transformer, self).__init__() 
        self.embeddings = nn.Embedding(vocab, d_model) 
        self.postionalencod = PositionalEncoding(seq_length, d_model) 
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList ([
            TransformerDecoderBlock(d_model, num_heads, d_ff, dropout)
        for _ in range(num_layers)])
        self.fc_out = nn.Linear(d_model, vocab) 

    def forward(self, x, mask):
        x = self.embeddings(x) 
        x = self.postionalencod(x) 
        for layer in self.layers:
            x = layer(x, mask) 
        
        return self.fc_out(x) 

# Initialize tokenizer
tokenizer = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

# Example data
texts = [
        "This is an example sentence.", 
         "Another sentence for training.",
         "Under the cover of darkness, he slipped past the guards and into the heavily fortified compound.",
        "Hidden in the shadows, she observed the clandestine meeting unfold before her.",
        "With nerves of steel, he decrypted the encrypted files, revealing the enemy's plans.",
        "Using state-of-the-art gadgets, she infiltrated the enemy's headquarters undetected.",
        "In the world of espionage, trust was a luxury few could afford.",
        "Betrayal lurked around every corner, testing the loyalty of even the most seasoned agents.",
        "In a game of cat and mouse, he outsmarted his pursuers at every turn.",
        "Behind enemy lines, she operated with precision, gathering invaluable intelligence.",
        "The stakes were high, but failure was not an option in their mission to save the world.",
        "In the murky world of espionage, secrets were currency, and betrayal was always just a whisper away.",
        "Cloaked in a disguise, he mingled with the crowd, keeping a watchful eye on his target.",
        "She pressed herself against the wall, listening intently to the conversation on the other side.",
        "With a flick of his wrist, he activated the hidden camera, capturing vital evidence.",
        "She knew that one wrong move could jeopardize the entire mission.",
        "He navigated the labyrinth of tunnels beneath the city, following the trail of breadcrumbs left by the enemy.",
        "In the world of espionage, loyalty was a rare commodity, easily bought and sold.",
        "She adjusted her earpiece, tuning in to the encrypted transmission from headquarters.",
        "He felt the weight of the microfilm hidden in his pocket, containing classified information that could change the course of history.",
        "With the enemy closing in, they had to think fast to evade capture.",
        "Every step was calculated, every move strategic, as they danced through the intricate web of deception.",
        "The tension in the air was palpable as they awaited the signal to proceed with the mission.",
    "With a code name and a false identity, he blended seamlessly into enemy territory.",
    "She glanced at her watch, counting down the seconds until the extraction team arrived.",
    "In the world of espionage, information was power, and they held the key to unlocking it.",
    "He carefully analyzed the cryptic message, searching for hidden meanings and clues.",
    "She sprinted down the dimly lit alley, adrenaline coursing through her veins.",
    "Under the guise of a tourist, he discretely gathered intelligence in plain sight.",
    "With each passing hour, the deadline for preventing disaster drew closer.",
    "The safe house provided temporary respite from the constant threat of surveillance.",
    "In a game where trust was a liability, she learned to rely only on herself.",
    "He exchanged a silent nod with his fellow agent, a silent understanding passing between them.",
    "The mission was fraught with danger, but they were trained to thrive in the face of adversity.",
    "She adjusted her sunglasses, scanning the crowded plaza for any signs of suspicious activity.",
    "With a flicker of uncertainty, he wondered if he could trust his informant's tip.",
    "They operated in the shadows, unseen and unheard, like ghosts in the night.",
    "The dossier contained classified information that could bring down governments if it fell into the wrong hands.",
    "She meticulously pieced together the puzzle, connecting the dots of a larger conspiracy.",
    "The double agent's loyalties were constantly in question, a dangerous wild card in the game of espionage.",
    "He slipped the microdot into his pocket, knowing its contents could change the course of history.",
    "The encrypted message held the key to unlocking the enemy's next move, but time was running out.",
    ]
max_length = 50

# Tokenize and encode the text data
encodings = tokenizer(texts, padding='max_length', truncation=True, max_length=max_length, return_tensors='pt')
input_ids = encodings['input_ids']

# Create a dataset and DataLoader
dataset = TensorDataset(input_ids)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True)

import torch.optim as optim

# Define model parameters
d_model = 256
d_ff = 2048
num_heads = 8
vocab_size = tokenizer.vocab_size
seq_length = max_length
num_layers = 6
dropout = 0.1

# Instantiate the model
model = Transformer(d_model, d_ff, num_heads, vocab_size, seq_length, num_layers, dropout)

# Define loss function and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)

# Training parameters
num_epochs = 10

# Training loop
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    epoch_loss = 0
    
    for batch in dataloader:
        inputs = batch[0]  # Get inputs from the batch
        targets = inputs  # In language modeling, the target is usually the same as the input
        mask = generate_squre_subsequent_mask(seq_length)  # Generate mask

        # Forward pass
        outputs = model(inputs, mask)
        outputs = outputs.view(-1, vocab_size)  # Flatten the outputs
        targets = targets.view(-1)  # Flatten the targets

        # Compute loss
        loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
        
        # Backward pass and optimization
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        epoch_loss += loss.item()
    
    print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}, Loss: {epoch_loss/len(dataloader)}')

torch.save(model.state_dict(), r'model.pth')

# Example prompt
prompt = "This is an"

# Tokenize the prompt
prompt_tokens = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors='pt')
input_ids = prompt_tokens['input_ids']

def generate_text(model, tokenizer, prompt, max_length=50, temperature=1.0):
    model.eval()  # Set the model to evaluation mode

    # Tokenize the prompt
    prompt_tokens = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors='pt')
    input_ids = prompt_tokens['input_ids']
    
    # Loop to generate tokens
    for _ in range(max_length):
        # Generate mask for the input
        mask = generate_squre_subsequent_mask(input_ids.size(1))

        # Forward pass to get logits
        with torch.no_grad():
            outputs = model(input_ids, mask[:, :input_ids.size(1)])  # Adjust mask size
            
        # Get the logits for the last token
        next_token_logits = outputs[:, -1, :] / temperature

        # Sample the next token from the logits
        next_token = torch.multinomial(torch.nn.functional.softmax(next_token_logits, dim=-1), num_samples=1)

        # Append the next token to the input_ids
        next_token = next_token.view(1, 1)  # Reshape to match input_ids
        input_ids = torch.cat([input_ids, next_token], dim=1)

        # Check if the generated token is the end-of-sequence token
        if next_token.item() == tokenizer.eos_token_id:
            break

    # Decode the generated tokens back to text
    generated_text = tokenizer.decode(input_ids[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
    return generated_text



# Example usage
generated_text = generate_text(model, tokenizer, prompt, max_length=50)
print(generated_text)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "e:\projects\transformer.py", line 281, in 
generated_text = generate_text(model, tokenizer, prompt, max_length=50)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "e:\projects\transformer.py", line 258, in generate_text
outputs = model(input_ids, mask[:, :input_ids.size(1)])  # Adjust mask size
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "E:\projects\venv1\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1532, in _wrapped_call_impl
return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "E:\projects\venv1\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1541, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "e:\projects\transformer.py", line 123, in forward
x = self.postionalencod(x)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "E:\projects\venv1\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1532, in _wrapped_call_impl
return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "E:\projects\venv1\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1541, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "e:\projects\transformer.py", line 28, in forward
return x + pos_encoding
~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (51) must match the size of tensor b (50) at non-singleton dimension 1
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (51) must match the size of tensor b (50) at non-singleton dimension 1

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
